# Good morning beautiful

Tags: adjectives, greetings

For quite some time I have greeted foreign/english girlfriends with "good morning, beautiful" in the morning - I'm from Germany, so English is not my first language, hence the question:

Today I wondered if "beautiful" is correct? Should it rather be

1) "Good morning, beauty"  or is

2) "Good morning, beautiful" (implying "good morning, beautiful woman")

correct as well?

Comment: #2 is correct. #1 makes no sense - just as "Good morning, truth" or "Good morning, world peace" would make no sense.

Comment: @michael.hor257k "Good morning beautiful" wouldn't make sense unless we knew it was addressed to someone beautiful looking. It's such a well-known expression we don't stop to think about its meaning, we just understand it. Vice versa I see nothing wrong with saying "Good morning/Hello world"

Comment: @Mari-LouA It's such a common expression, we don't need to stop to think about its meaning. It is clearly addressed to the present person and intended as a compliment. Whether the person is in fact beautiful or not is entirely irrelevant. -- "Good morning/Hello world" has a different structure than OP's first sentence and my subversions of it.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I disagree that #1 `makes no sense` it does, in context, but we just don't say it. Common nouns, as well as adjectives, can be greeted in the morning: "Good morning laptop",  "Good morning first day of the year" "Goodmorning sunshine" Abstract nouns? *Hello silence, my old friend* (famous line of a Paul Simon's song). What's wrong with "Hello beauty"? It makes sense to me.

Comment: @Mari-LouA "Good morning, beauty" would make sense if *beauty* were meant as a form of address. However, I am not aware of such usage being idiomatic (perhaps because #2 is).  So I would interpret it as referring to some abstract virtue - which in turn makes no sense in the given context.

Comment: "Not idiomatic" is not the same as "makes no sense". "Michael Hor has seven legs" is certainly not a common idiom. But its meaning is perfectly clear.

Comment: They are both fine, including the first one. The first one could also be *Good morning,* ***my*** *beauty.*

Comment: @RegDwigнt It makes no sense to say such thing (both OP's 1st sentence and your example).